# Position textfield as 'attached' to the other field

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui-react

I have the following layout:

[image]

When the screen size is changed I want the text field to stay always 'attached' to the last radio button having `1em` distance between them. The problem is that the radio button group is one `div` and the text field is another. Is there a way of specifying `css` rules on the text field `only` to achieve such positioning? If not, what could be done otherwise? I am using `semantic-ui-react` and due to the nature of the project structure can only position the radio button group and the textfield in two different `Form.Group`s'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use display the flex property for this design. It will always align at the bottom from the last radio button. You just need to add to lines in CSS. Here is the pen: https://codepen.io/Mak0619/pen/bPYXyg

HTML:

```html
<div class="radio-button-grop">
  <div class="bd-example">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" checked="">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
      Default radio
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
      Second default radio
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check disabled">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3" value="option3" disabled="">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
      Disabled radio
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-field">
    <input type="text"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.radio-button-grop{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.text-field{
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it positioned text field on below the last radio button. At least in the layout that I have it does it :( I added `important!` to all of the properties, but it did not help. Besides, from `grouped` radio button group (that is customized `Form.Group` of `semantic-ui-react`) became `inline` positioning radio buttons horizontally instead of vertically.

Comment: After final trials, I made it work and it was just a matter of following your layout more closely